# looping through html5 data hooks in coffeescript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I have a product listing page with main product images and variant thumbnails below each main image. When you hover over a thumbnail it should change the main image to that of the thumbnail. I almost have it working except for the fact that when you hover over a thumbnail it changes the main image for every product on the page, not just the product the thumbnail is below.

Each main image is assigned it's product_id via ruby and html5:

```
<div class="main-image" data-productid="<%= product.id %>">
  <%= link_to large_image(product, :itemprop => "image", :class => "product-image"), product, :itemprop => 'url' %>
</div><!-- main-image-->
```

I believe I need to loop through my coffeescript code separately for each product, but I'm not sure how to execute it. Here's what I have now, and its changing images for all products:

```
add_image_handlers = ->

  thumbnails = ($ '.product-images ul.thumbnails')
  ($ '.main-image').data 'selectedThumb', 'productid', ($ '.main-image img').attr('src')
  thumbnails.find('li').eq(0).addClass 'selected'
  thumbnails.find('a').on 'click', (event) ->
    ($ '.main-image').data 'selectedThumb', ($ event.currentTarget).attr('href')
    ($ '.main-image').data 'selectedThumbId', ($ event.currentTarget).parent().attr('id')
    ($ this).mouseout ->
      thumbnails.find('li').removeClass 'selected'
      ($ event.currentTarget).parent('li').addClass 'selected'
    false

  thumbnails.find('li').on 'mouseenter', (event) ->
    ($ '.main-image img').attr 'src', ($ event.currentTarget).find('a').attr('href')

  thumbnails.find('li').on 'mouseleave', (event) ->
    ($ '.main-image img').attr 'src', ($ '.main-image').data('selectedThumb')

show_variant_images = (variant_id) ->
  ($ 'li.vtmb').hide()
  ($ 'li.vtmb-' + variant_id).show()
  currentThumb = ($ '#' + ($ '.main-image').data('selectedThumbId'))
  if not currentThumb.hasClass('vtmb-' + variant_id)
    thumb = ($ ($ 'ul.thumbnails li:visible.vtmb').eq(0))
    thumb = ($ ($ 'ul.thumbnails li:visible').eq(0)) unless thumb.length > 0
    newImg = thumb.find('a').attr('href')
    ($ 'ul.thumbnails li').removeClass 'selected'
    thumb.addClass 'selected'
    ($ '.main-image img').attr 'src', newImg
    ($ '.main-image').data 'selectedThumb', newImg
    ($ '.main-image').data 'selectedThumbId', thumb.attr('id')

update_variant_price = (variant) ->
  variant_price = variant.data('price')
  ($ '.price.selling').text(variant_price) if variant_price

$ ->
  add_image_handlers()
  show_variant_images ($ '#product-variants input[type="radio"]').eq(0).attr('value') if          ($ '#product-variants input[type="radio"]').length > 0
($ '#product-variants input[type="radio"]').click (event) ->
show_variant_images @value
update_variant_price ($ this)
```

I think I need to loop through this code for each 'productid' data hook on the page but I'm not sure.

Thank you!

Comment: You have a jQuery bug in your 'mouseenter' expression.  ` ($ '.main-image img')` will change *all* of the images, not just the one associated with the event.

`($ event.currentTarget).closest('.main-image').find('img').attr 'src', ...`  Is much closer to what you want.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Do you know how I would include the productid data element into that? Also, here's a coffeescript snippet i wrote which iterates through all the data elements, pulling the productid from each image, `$.each $(".main-image"), (index, elem) ->
  console.log $(elem).data("productid")` but I don't know how to embed it in the above file so that it executes all that code on each productid.

Thank you!

Comment: For each product, I would create a DIV with the data strings for the various qualities I cared about: `<div class="product" data-productID="123" ... >` etc, and then, regardless of the event, I would search for `closest('.product')` and pull out all the data I cared about.

Or, I would use a data-oriented MVVM framework like Backbone or Angular, and let it do all the work for me.